# Mutual Fund API

Tags: api, finance

I am looking for a free financial stock quote API that quotes historical information for Mutual Funds. Preferably JSON REST. I used to use Google, Yahoo but both are no longer available. All current free APIs seem to cover stocks but not mutual funds.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried https://www.quandl.com/ ?

Comment: Free? Otherwise what budget for how many queries per day? Also, what license do you need? Personal use, commercial use, redistribution?

Comment: @zz quandl is not free unfortunately. But ty for the suggestion.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul This is for personal use so the budget is minimal. I expect maybe once a day I will want to retrieve historical data a dozen mutual funds going back 5/10 years. The objective is to produce line graphs with the data comparing the funds activity over time periods. A separate time period graph will be produced for activity over the past week, month, quarter, year, 3 years, 5 years, 10 years.

Comment: Did you find any API? I'm also searching for a free api for mutual funds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I was unable to find a completely free solution, I did find:

https://www.alphavantage.co

Alpha provides 5 free API requests a minute, up to 500 a day.

Besides the throttling, the only downside is that mutual funds data only update once a day, usually not until the morning after.